# I have a list of list in python and I want to strip some characters from every two elements

Tags: python, arrays, list

Probably this simle but somehow I am not able to resolve this. I have a list of list from which I want to strip some characters from every two elements and make another list of list

```
list = [['A*68:02:01:03', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], 
        ['A*68:02:01:02', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], 
        ['A*68:02:01:01', 'A*33:01:01', '1']]

required output = [['A*68:02', 'A*33:01', '1'], 
                   ['A*68:02', 'A*33:01', '1'], 
                   ['A*68:02', 'A*33:01', '1']]
```

Finally I want to print only unique elements. Like in the above case all three elements are same so the output should be:

```
output = ['A*68:02', 'A*33:01', '1']
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: For list-like things that are unique, take a look at [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst = [['A*68:02:01:03', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], ['A*68:02:01:02', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], ['A*68:02:01:01', 'A*33:01:01', '1']]
>>> newLst = [tuple(':'.join(data.split(':', 2)[:2]) for data in sublist) for sublist in lst]
>>> set(newLst)
{('A*68:02', 'A*33:01', '1')}
```

The interesting bit is the `':'.join(data.split(':', 2)[:2]`. The will split `data` by colons, take only the first two parts and join them again. That way, we strip everything off after the second colon (including that).

The rest is just a list comprehension to go through the nested list. We also need to convert the inner list to a tuple, so they are hashable when we call `set()` on it. Doing that will get rid of all duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
lst = [['A*68:02:01:03', 'A*33:01:01', '1'],
       ['A*68:02:01:02', 'A*33:01:01', '1'],
       ['A*68:02:01:01', 'A*33:01:01', '1']]

output = []

for item in lst:
    processed = [":".join(s.split(":")[:2]) for s in item]
    if processed not in output:
        output.append(processed)
```

**Note**: don't call your own variables things like `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def prefix(string):
    """
    Returns the prefix of a string, including all characters 
    up until the second colon. 
    """
    return ":".join(string.split(":", 2)[:2])

def unique(iterable):
    """
    Returns the unique elements in iterable, maintaining the 
    elements' relative order.
    """
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for el in iterable:
        if el not in seen:
            seen.add(el)
            result.append(el)
    return result

L = [
    ['A*68:02:01:03', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], 
    ['A*68:02:01:02', 'A*33:01:01', '1'], 
    ['A*68:02:01:01', 'A*33:01:01', '1'],
]
prefixes = [(prefix(el[0]), prefix(el[1]), el[2]) for el in L]

# The built-in class set accepts an iterable and returns a set, 
# an object with all duplicate elements removed. Since sets are
# unordered, converting the set back to a list will likely 
# produce a list in which the original elements have lost their
# relative order.
# If this is a problem you can use the unique function from above.
uniq = list(set(prefixes))

# If you really need a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples.
uniq = [list(el) for el in uniq]
```

I have renamed your input list to L, because naming it `list` shadows the built-in function list.